# Uncaught TypeError: scrollIntoView is not a function. Child element isn't showing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with "scrollIntoView". It is currently not working. I am trying to make a list item element with class "active" to be visible. There is an unordered list with fixed height that holds multiple elements. Some of the elements aren't visible and you must scroll to them. I am trying to use "scrollIntoView()" but it's not working. Please help me.

```js
function _ScrollTopImageNav() {
    var imageElement = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    imageElement.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth"
    });
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 30px;
}

ul > li {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
}

ul > li + li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

ul > li.active {
background-color: red;
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="active"></li>
</ul>

<a href="#" onclick="_ScrollTopImageNav()"> show element</a>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a (live) `HTMLCollection`, not a node, therefore the `HTMLCollection` has no `scrollIntoView` method, since that's a node method, not a `HTMLCollection` method .... if you know you just want the FIRST (or ONLY) such element, use `document.querySelector('.active')` instead - note the `.` in front of `active`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns array, but you need single element, access it using

```
imageElement[0].scrollIntoView
```

Also, seems like `behavior: "smooth"` is not supported in [some browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility)

Below working demo

```js
function _ScrollTopImageNav() {
  var imageElement = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  imageElement[0].scrollIntoView();
}
```

```css
  ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 30px;
}

ul>li {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
}

ul>li+li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

ul>li.active {
  background-color: red;
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="active"></li>
</ul>

<a href="#" onclick="_ScrollTopImageNav()"> show element</a>
```

Comment: It's not an array, but an array-like object.